# JSF 2 Session Beans Problems

Tags: session, jsf-2, myfaces, viewexpiredexception

I have a JSF 2.1 (MyFaces) app running using several Session Beans (All the beans are session beans).
The timeout is defined in web.xml as such:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>3600</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Which translates to 1 hour.

The problem is that on normal usage I get the `No Saved View...` exception:

```
SEVERE: An exception occurred
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /mainPanel.jsfNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /mainPanel.jsf
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:128)
```

The beans are, currently, defined in faces-config.xml for compatibility with Eclipse's ide.

I'm not sure what could be causing this and it's definitely not timeout.
Any ideas what could be the problem?

If there is any further information I can provide, let me know..

Thanks!

P.S - there is no `jsf-2.1` tag

**Update 1** I just figured 60 meant 1 minute! :-) That could be the problem. I will close the question if it turns out that way

**Update 2** Thats wasn't it... Some more information That might be helpful:

1. While the error is specifically for `/mainPanel.jsf`, this is actually a composition of xhtml's using `<ui:include>`
2. It happends only when I click one specific point in the app. The code that runs as a result of the click is:

`Jquery` Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#someTable tr:not(:first)").click(function(event) {

            var someValue = $(this).find("input:hidden").val();
            $('#currently_selected').val(someValue );
            $('#currently_selected').change();

        });
    });
```

`JSF 2` Code:

```
<h:form prependId="false" class="hide">
    <h:inputText value="#{someBean.someBeanValue}">
        <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{someBean.someBeanValueChanged}" render=":anotherForm"
            onevent="ifCompleteSetWindowHash" />
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first view it seems to be some side effect over javax.faces.ViewState hidden field. If this field is ovewritten, a ViewExpiredException will be thrown. Try to do the same you are doing with other different javascript code.

Anyway it is not related to your session-config parameter. The information provided here is insuficient to reproduce it. If the previous suggestion does not solve your problem, please create an issue on [MyFaces Issue Tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES) and attach an example. In this way you'll get it solved.

Comment: Thanks @Lu4242, i've changed some `h:inputHidden` components to `h:inputText class="hide"` and the problem seems to have disappeared. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `$` symbol is a reserved character for EL expressions in JSF *(EDIT: As noted below, the '$' alone is not reserved, however third party component libararies may use various javascript libraries that could have a naming conflict with jQuery).*  Try changing your jQuery function calls to the explicit long form name and see if that makes a difference.

Eg. Instead of...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Do this...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: That is not true. Only `${...}` (including the curly braces) is reserved. As to jQuery, that is only the case when `$()` function is already in use by another JS library like Prototype, Scriptaculous, etc which would then result in unknown/undefinied function name JS errors.

Comment: Yes thats more correct! Many third party component libararies like Primefaces use such JS libraries within many of their components. I feel it is a best practice because of this to use the long form for jQuery within any JSF application even if no third party component libraries exist, to avoid such naming conflicts.  This could still be the OP's problem.

Comment: I don't have the impression either that this is a jQuery problem. The symptoms do not point in this direction.